# Specify different voices for specific content in web page

Tags: javascript, css, accessibility, text-to-speech

I have tried to find information about writing web pages that will be accessible to blind people and haven't found much useful information yet. Specifically, what I'm looking for is how to give specific instructions to screen readers in general, about how to read the content of my pages. I know that overriding user settings for a screen reader could be perceived as a type of annoyance but, the content I'm looking to make accessible is poetry, plays, stories, and other types of creative writing. Being that there are often many different characters speaking within the same document, it would be great if there were a way for me to specify different characteristics about the screen readers voice in order to allow the blind person (or anyone really) the opportunity to audibly distinguish the separate speaking characters. Right now, what I'm doing is using a narrator to tell the listener who is speaking, which is very unnatural and distracting.

An example of content could be:

> Brenda: Hey Jimmy! What's up?
>
> Jimmy: Brenda! Look look! You sound like a lady and I sound like a
> man!
>
> Slow Kid: Ooh... and I sound very very slow...

So, is there any way for me to define tags, attributes, or somehow attach a script to elements in order to change the speaking voice on specific content in a web page? Is there a standard defined that I can work with in order to present the spoken text in a similar fashion in IE and Firefox? What about native browser support, I've seen a few plugins for screen reading but I'm curious if there is any text to speech support built into IE or Firefox so I don't have to install a plugin.

Comment: Found this somewhat related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6607571/1494314 and the only answer at this time talks about how aural style sheets both, have been superseded by CSS3's Speech module and, require an external application which often doesn't utilize the style sheet.

Comment: Link to CSS speech module: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-speech/

Comment: Found this: "W3C Invites Implementations of CSS Speech Module" from March 20, 2012 http://www.w3.org/News/2012#entry-9392

Comment: Link to the Voice Browser Working group: http://www.w3.org/Voice/

Comment: Link to Opera's tutorial "How to Add Voice Interactivity to Your Site": http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/add-voice-interactivity-to-your-site/

An informational note at the top of the page reads: "July 27th 2011: Please note that Voice only works in Opera on Windows 2000/XP, and we no longer officially support it."

Comment: MSDN VoiceXML tutorial "VoiceXML Tutorial - Introduction": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769501.aspx

Comment: Link to W3C "Voice Extensible Markup Language (VoiceXML) 2.1": http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-voicexml21-20070619/

Comment: Link to "Firefox:2.0 Accessibility: Crazy blind dude recommendations": https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox:2.0_Accessibility

Note: googling for Firefox VoiceXML... Did they ever implement this or not?

Comment: Link to Voxeo's "VoiceXML Development Guide Version 2.1": http://www.vxml.org/

Comment: Link to PHP VoiceXML Magazine: http://voicexml.phpmagazine.net/

This sounds complicated but if a browser could interact with it instead of a phone... I wonder if I shouldn't be trying to do this with skype but I want to give both the visual and audible presentation options on one page...

Comment: Link to W3 Working Draft "Voice Extensible Markup Language (VoiceXML) 3.0" : http://www.w3.org/TR/voicexml30/

Comment: All links I've found to the "tadpole" extension for Firefox that point to IBM's developer works seem to be broken. They're redirected to alphaWorks, and searching the site for tadpole returns no hits... where did it go?

note: http://www.voiceingov.org/blog/?p=123
Found some old forum about Tadpole, doesn't give much info: VoiceXML Interpreter for Firefox Tadpole Extension - http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=1204&start=0

Comment: giving up, not because the idea is useless but because it appears that nobody really cares to implement a screen reader in a normal browser.

I think it would be really cool to be able to write web pages that screen readers could attempt to speak out in context. It really sucks that apparently nobody else feels the same way.

Comment: My answer was going to basically echo what you summed up here. There is a number of (W3C) groups working on this, but no browser really supports it. My gut says Opera's built-in speech output can do some pf this, but in general it isn't a viable solution for people with vision imparments due to functionality. I thought I heard some chatter for Chrome on this. There is a Google Group "accessible", that you may want to search. I forget if the discussion was about your question or dictating wjat voice to use in general.

Comment: Thanks Ryan! I found the group but I can't seem to find anything specific to my question. Good find though. :D

Answer (score 1):

The only direction I could point you in at the moment is http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/aural.html and http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-speech/#aural-model.

There aren't a lot of truly helpful resource in the wild for the optimisation of assistive technologies like screen readers. But perhaps some other members, more knowledgeable than I, might be able to provide greater assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing a similar challenge. (I want to distinguish the semantics of different kinds of content using voice 'character').

I'm quite fond of eSpeak, and have used it extensively for prototyping spoken content before we get the voice actors in. I therefore find speak.js a very interesting piece of work.

However, I would be wary of a roll-your-own solution for accessibility because I know that screenreader users often have very specific preferences about speech settings (speed, pitch, timbre, gender, accent etc.)

If you do go down the path you propose, make sure your users can tweak the settings easily (as they can with most screenreader software), and that those settings are saved between visits (e.g. with a cookie). This seems like a lot of work to do properly. If you have the time and budget, then great!

Now I'm off to visit those css3-speech links.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Migrating the solution from the question to an answer:</sub>

> **A hackers way of doing it in Firefox:**
>
> Here's something slightly promising... "speak.js" to quote:
>
> > "speak.js is a port of eSpeak, an open source speech synthesizer, from
> > C++ to JavaScript using Emscripten."
>
> An [article about speak.js on Mozilla's Dev blog](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/08/speak-js-text-to-speech-on-the-web/).
>
> Source on [speak.js' GitHub page](https://github.com/kripken/speak.js): kripken/speak.js quoting from
> the readme.markdown:
>
> > "Options
> >
> > You can also specify some options with calling speak(), by doing
> >
> > `speak('hello world', { option1: value1, option2: value2 .. })`
> >
> > available options are:
> >
> > ```
> > amplitude: How loud the voice will be (default: 100)
> > pitch: The voice pitch (default: 50)
> > speed: The speed at which to talk (words per minute) (default: 175)
> > voice: Which voice to use 
> >        (for a non-default voice, requires you to build speak.js
> >        to include the proper data. See Language Support
> >        below) (default: en/en-us)
> > wordgap: Additional gap between words in 10 ms units (default: 0)
> > noWorker: Do not use a web worker (see below in 'Architecture')
> > ```
> >
> > For example
> >
> > `speak('hello world', { pitch: 100 })`
> >
> > will talk in a very high-pitched voice."
>
> **Note:**
>
> This only works in Firefox at the moment. While it's not exactly what
> I was looking for, it seems entirely possible to use JavaScript to
> parse through the HTML and use attributes to trigger the "speak"
> command with any options I'd like. This will take a little work but,
> in the end I might end up with a bot that can try to read a page in
> context!