# A way to mute an iframe using jQuery or CSS?

Tags: javascript, iframe, vimeo, mute, vimeo-api

Is there a way to mute the audio of an iframe using jQuery or CSS?

This is the iframe I need to mute

```
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/4415083?api=1;title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=d01e2f&amp;autoplay=1" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

Comment: You didn't search enough! Read it here http://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api

Comment: Hi @BojanPetkovski I have tried this all day and nothing. Also other forums have said that you can not do it through any vimeo api and it has to be code targeting the actual iframe and not the video. Thanks though Ill keep trying

Comment: @BojanPetkovski Yes, there is an API for Vimeo, but you can't use it from a parent document targeting an iframe because of the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: @feeela you can use it, it's kind of the point of exposing an API, isnt it? The API is based on `window.postMessage` and works just fine cross-origin, see fiddle links in my answer below :)

Comment: OK, never heard about `Window.postMessage`. Cool, today I've learned something new…

Comment: @feeela then you're in for a treat :) It opens great possibilities for cross-window communication.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Include this library in your page: https://github.com/vimeo/player-api/tree/master/javascript like this

`<script src="//f.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js"></script>`

This code will send an API call to vimeo player to set the volume to 0 once the player is ready, based on http://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api

```
// you may need another way of getting reference to the iframe:
var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
var player = $f( iframe );

 player.addEvent('ready', function() {
     player.api('setVolume', 0); 
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/87dsjL8q/

Or, without the external library:

```
iframe.contentWindow.postMessage('{"method":"setVolume", "value":0}','*');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/87dsjL8q/1/

Comment: this has been the most promising of the day but for some reason I still can not get it working please please please look here and see if you can tell me why? http://www.cambridgedesign.company/graphic.html

Comment: @DanielNolan you have `Uncaught ReferenceError: $f is not defined`, which means you need to add the library, I've edited the answet to be more clear.

Comment: @DanielNolan then you have more than one `<iframe>` on your page, the simplest solution would be to add an id attribute to it (for example `<iframe id="mute-this" ... >`, then `var iframe = document.getElementById('mute-this')` in the JS.

Comment: you truly are lovely, and I did what you said and uploaded it online but still nothing. :(

Comment: @DanielNolan move the script to the bottom of the page, now it executes when the iframe isn't there yet.

Comment: its made it worse, Im going to give up now but thanks for trying. this website stuff is just too hard. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 3):

Here you are with a button based on previous answers http://jsfiddle.net/qumg6e7h/

```
$('button').on('click', function () {
    var iframe = $(this).prev('iframe')[0];

    if ($(this).hasClass('mute')) {
        $(this).removeClass('mute').text('Mute');
        iframe.contentWindow.postMessage('{"method":"setVolume", "value":1}', '*');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('mute').text('Unmute');
        iframe.contentWindow.postMessage('{"method":"setVolume", "value":0}', '*');
    }
});
```

You can have as many iframes as you like. Just add the button after the iframe and on click mute/unmute the video :)

Answer (score 2):

You can only mute HTML5 `audio` and `video` elements.

An iframe does not have an audio API, so you can't mute anything using JS on that element. If you can find a workaround to the restrictions from the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), you maybe can select the real audio or video element inside the iframe and mute that.

There is a [W3C recommendation for “aural style sheets”](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/aural.html#volume-props), but I don't know how the browser support for that look like. Using those properties you probably could mute any HTML element:

```
iframe {
    volume: silent;
}
```

Comment: thanks for being DECENT about it, yeah Ive tried this too with no joy, it just seems that maybe it cant be done... maybe time to use youtube instead of vimeo! lol

Comment: @DanielNolan That is a technical limitation of JS, not one of Vimeo vs. Youtube (At least Vimeo doesn't surprisingly delete or block you videos for no reason…)

Comment: Aural style sheets are for screenreaders and other accessibility tools http://stackoverflow.com/a/6607718/873565